# I cant make socket.on connection successfully in react native

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I'm trying to create a mini chat app so I need to use socket connection but I can't make the connection. I tried many things but nothing solved my problem.

My `index.js` file:

```
 var  express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var server = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello');
   });
 server.listen(3000);
```

Other that I'm using `detail.js` file:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
  componentDidMount(){
      
     var socket = io('http://localhost:3000',connectionConfig);
     socket.on('connect',function(){
         console.log('connected');
     })
}
```

When I open debugging page, 'connected' doesn't show up